# Mean distance beween nearest 2 coordinates

Tags: list-manipulation, distance, nearest

I have as an example the following 2d-coordinates:

```
list={{533.286, 574.643}, {13.4032, 571.984}, {188.4, 573.9}, {328.603, 
  572.064}, {623.13, 571.685}, {705.458, 572.25}, {413.912, 
  569.794}, {503.067, 567.867}, {70.5, 566.094}, {158.737, 
  565.737}, {244.952, 566.339}, {593.227, 563.091}, {675.5, 560.796}}
```

[image]

How can I fastest calculate the mean of the next nearest neighbor distances, *not counting duplicates*?

I used the code of Szabolcs (below) and superposed the connection lines:

[image]

Another example with more coordinates and same x and y aspect ratio gives (which helps):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Mean[
  EdgeList@NearestNeighborGraph[list, 1] /. 
  UndirectedEdge -> EuclideanDistance
]
```

Comment: I think that is the solution ... is it possible to show the connection lines to the next neighbors in the upper image? Then I am convinced.

Comment: @mrz Yes, `NearestNeighborGraph[list, 1]` will show that.  Now what is bother me is that `NearestNeighborGraph[list]` does not connect all points when I use your coordinates.  This is weird, and I think it's incorrect.  I just wrote to support to ask about it.

Comment: @Szalbos: What do think about the other data set (please see plots above)? Do you see there the same problem? I only want to see  connections between next neighbors. To me your solution NearestNeighborGraph[list, 1] looks correct.

Comment: @mrz Yes, if you use `NearestNeighborGraph[list, 1]`, it seems to always return the correct result.  But `NearestNeighborGraph[list]` (without the second argument) seems not to connect each point in some rare cases.

Answer (score 5):

**Correction**
I have voted for Szabolcs excellent answer. My original post was aimed to confirm result and though producing a correct result for this particular set of points it was fundamentally flawed.

I post now a corrected version to deal with fundamental error pointed out by Dr.belisarius (in dealing with nearest points common to different  points):

```
test = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {12, 0}};
f[u_] := Mean@
  Values[GroupBy[
    Sort[{##}] -> EuclideanDistance[##] & @@@ (Nearest[u, #, 2] & /@ 
       u), First -> Last, First]]
e[u_] := Keys[
  GroupBy[Sort[{##}] -> 
      EuclideanDistance[##] & @@@ (Nearest[u, #, 2] & /@ u), 
   First -> Last, First]]
f[list]
f[test]
Show[Graphics[MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #1] &, list], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True], Graphics[Line /@ e[list]]]
```

`f[list]` yielding: 51.0703 and `f[test]` (from belisarius): 11/3.

The graphic is consistent with the nearest neighbor graph:

[image]

Comment: Does this work with `list ={{1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{12,0}}` or does it return `5`?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Thank you!  I have made a mistake.(1+1+9)/4=11/3...min of distance: 1,1,,9...so you are right the union collapses to 5! Feeling stupid now...have hopefully corrected...Szabolcs answer is wonderful and why I voted for it, Thank you again for vigilance :)

Comment: `f = Nearest[list]; EuclideanDistance @@@ (Sort /@ ({#, Last@f[#, 2]} & /@ list) // 
    Union) // Mean` in V9

Comment: @Dr.belisarius thank you...my brain is too rattled right now...is this a neater way or exposure of another error? Off to sleep either way...what is 2 2 argument f?

Comment: It's a V9 calc,similar to yours. `f[#,2]` is the same as `Nearest[list, #, 2]`, but usually better because it precalculates the `NearestFunction`.

Answer (score 4):

```
list =
  {{533.286, 574.643}, {13.4032, 571.984}, {188.4, 573.9}, {328.603, 572.064}, 
   {623.13, 571.685}, {705.458, 572.25}, {413.912, 569.794}, 
   {503.067, 567.867}, {70.5, 566.094}, {158.737, 565.737},
   {244.952, 566.339}, {593.227, 563.091}, {675.5, 560.796}};

res = 
   Union@Map[Sort, {#, Flatten@Nearest[DeleteCases[list, #], #]} & /@ list];

dis = EuclideanDistance @@@ res;

Mean@dis
```

> 51.0703

```
bub =
  BubbleChart[
   Block[{i = 1},  res /. {a_Real, b_} :> {a, b, Riffle[dis, dis][[i++]]}],
   ChartStyle -> Opacity@0.5];

arr = Graphics[Arrow /@ res];

txt =
  Graphics@MapThread[Text, 
     {Partition[Flatten[Position[list, #] & /@ Flatten[res, 1]], 2], 
      res[[All, 1]]}];

Show[
 bub, arr, txt,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: I like type use of bubble chart :)